# How do I reset my desktop computer with pre loaded Ubuntu 13.1 to first start?

Tags: restart

I am brand new to the Ubuntu community and am already in trouble.  I recently purchased a new system76 ratel performance desktop with pre-loaded Ubuntu 13.10.  Upon first start of the system, no video output was displaying.  I turned the system off and tried again using a DVI cable and the video output came through perfectly.  However, rather than running me through the install menu, I was sent directly to the login screen.  I was never asked to create a username or password and can only log in as a guest.  How to I go back to the install 'wizard' and create a main user?  I would greatly appreciate your assistance as I am so stoked to get this thing working and my nerves are being overtaxed trying to figure this problem out.  Thank you in advance.

Adam

Comment: I am not sure how system 76 sets up their systems, I think this might be specific to system 76 because you don't need to do the full installation like normal. From what I hear System 76 is very easy to approach, so I would consider contacting them about your problems in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have contacted them, but I am not sure it is something they can fix. It seems by starting it for the first time and then shutting it off without doing anything for the first time forced it to go straight to default of no main user.  Any suggestions on how I can go back to scratch?

Comment: I found this on system76's website, not sure if it will help.... http://knowledge76.com/index.php/Restoring_Your_System

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work, but you can give it a try:

log in under the guest account, now go to your system settings (the icon with a gear) and under System to 'User Accounts'. hit the + sign in the lower left to add a account. It should be an Administrator. Here is where it might go wrong, because I think it will ask for a password, and you probably don't have one. If not, you can add a password for the account by hitting the box next to password and than you are setup.

If this doesn't work and since you have nothing on your computer jet it might be easiest to reinstall Ubuntu, system 76 has instructions for that [here](http://knowledge76.com/index.php/Restoring_Your_System).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this problem; it's caused by a bug with Ubuntu's OEM configuration and an interaction with plugging your monitor into the onboard (instead of Nvidia) ports.

Go ahead and turn the computer off, then turn it back on. When you see the first purple screen, press the reset button on the front (the upside-down triangle). This will cause the system to reboot again. When it gets past the System76 logo, it should go to the GRUB menu. Choose "Advanced Option for Ubuntu", then select the first option with "Recovery Mode" listed in it and press enter.

Once the system starts up into the recovery menu, choose the Root Shell option, then enter in this command:

mount -o remount,rw /

Next, you can create a new user by entering this command:

adduser name

And filling out the information. Only the Full Name and Password fields are required; the rest are optional. Be sure to replace "name" with the username you want.

Next enter these commands:

adduser name adm
adduser name sudo
reboot

Again, replace "name" with the username you used for the first command. These will make your user an administrator, then reboot your system At this point you should be able to log in and use the System Settings panel to set up your timezone, keyboard layout, and language preferences.